# Only add csv values to PHP array that do not contain string

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, csv

I'm trying to create an array of values ($import_data) from a csv file that contains about 42,000 rows, each row contains an SKU. I only want to add the values to the array which DO NOT contain the string "CNV". Is there an easy way to do this?

Here is how I am adding the values from the CSV to the array:

```
while ( ( $line = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $post_data['import_csv_separator']) ) !== FALSE ) {
            $import_data[] = $line;
        }
```

Comment: have you tried using strpos() function ?

Comment: something like this maybe: if (strpos($line, "CNV") === false){ // do something}

Comment: This helped me so much! Thank you! I'll answer my question with my final code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it!

```
         while ( ( $line = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $post_data['import_csv_separator']) ) !== FALSE ) {
            $test_str = print_r($line,true);
            if (strpos($test_str, "CNV") === false){ // add it
            $import_data[] = $line;
         }
```